# c# multiple tasks wait all with "callback"

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, .net-8.0

I'm new to c# and .net 8 I would like to know what would be the cleanest way to start x tasks in parallel, await them all but for each one have a delegate (callback) that should be executed and then once everything is done move on.

Case is like that: start 10 different operations, for each one operation once its done log different message and save something different to database, Once everything is completed move on.

I know that there is Task.WhenAll but then I would need to wait for all tasks to be completed and then for each one execute mentioned callback operation.

In pseudocode I would like it to look like that:

`Task t1 = new Task<Result> DoSomething()`

`Task t2 = new Task<Result> DoSomething2()`

```
//Now something that Im missing

t1.OnComplete(DoSomethingAck())

t2.OnComplete(DoSomething2Ack())

Task.WhenAll(t1, t2) ... move on`
```

Comment: For your call back you could wrap the `DoSomething()` calls in a method and have the method execute the call back.  Then you could use Task.WhenAll to know when everything is done.

Comment: Also you need `await Task.WhenAll`